# How to specify eager loading of associations in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, eager-loading

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :Bs
  has_many :Cs
  ...
end
```

I wish to load all of B's and C's whenever I do a query on A, say `A.where(name: :abc)`, with a single query, instead of multiple calls to database.

I don't wish to specify `.includes` for every query I run. How do I specify eager loading in the model itself?

I looked many similar question and tried do this but it does not work:

```
default_scope :include => [:Bs, :Cs]
```

Comment: `default_scope { includes(:Bs, :Cs) }`. As far as I know the scope takes a block not a hash of options. I just tried it in the rails console and seems to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`default_scope { includes(:Bs, :Cs) }` should do it.

As far as I know the scope takes a block as argument not a hash of options. I just tried it in the rails console and seems to work.