# Rails: Preloading a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Trailer model and each Trailer belongs_to a Movie, and a Movie has_many :releases. And Trailer has_many :releases through :movie

Release has a column :medium which can be "Netflix", "Theater", or "Torrent".

In my controller:

```
@trailers = Trailer.all
```

In my view, I want to check the releases of each trailer:

```
<%= render @trailers %>
```

then:

```
if trailer.releases.where(medium:"Torrent").first
  # show a Torrent icon
end
```

Is there a way to preload trailer.releases so that I'm not hammering the DB and calling `trailer.releases.where(medium:"Torrent").first, trailer.releases.where(medium:"Netflix").first, trailer.releases.where(medium:"Theater").first` for each trailer that gets rendered?

How do I optimize this?

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374387/how-to-specify-eager-loading-of-associations-in-rails-model/35374496#35374496)

Comment: Basically what you have to do is to add a default_scope to your `Trailer` model. If you don't want to include the releases anywhere in the app you could use a named scope instead of `default_scope`

Answer (score 0):

Try in controller:

```
@trailers = Trailer.all # 1 query to DB
@movies_releases = %w(Torrent Netflix Theater).map do |medium|
  [medium, Release.where(medium: medium).pluck('DISTINCT movie_id')]
end.to_h # 3 queries to DB
```

And then in view:

```
if @movies_releases['Torrent'].include?(trailer.movie_id)
  # show a Torrent icon
end
```